# Office 365 - will access/refresh tokens be invalidated as a result of switching a managed domain to federated?

Tags: azure, outlook, office365, ws-federation, refresh-token

In other words, will existing users who belong to a managed Office 365 domain be asked to re-authenticate (ex. in Outlook client) as a result of changing the authentication method of the Office 365 domain to federated?

I am aware that users are forced to re-authenticate (ex. in Outlook client) upon password change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems as though you will need to rea-authenticate when you convert from managed to federate. Please view the link below for a step by step conversion guide.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/02/06/convert-a-managed-domain-in-azure-ad-to-a-federated-domain-using-adfs-for-on-premises-authentication-step-by-step/

Comment: Please share the source of your answer. That link does not confirm your answer.

Comment: Please refer to this link:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2530590/troubleshoot-account-issues-for-federated-users-in-office-365-azure-or. Hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft support personnel and also as per my own experience, users are NOT forced to re-authenticate as a result of federating the Office 365 domain. In other words, a user's refresh token is NOT revoked simply as a result of federating the Office 365 domain.